# $L_1$-convergence in the Lebesgue differentiation theorem for general Radon measures?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a (non-negative) measure on $\mathbb R$ and let $f \in L_1(\mu)$. For all $h > 0$ and ($\mu$-almost-)all $x \in \mathbb R$, let
$$
f_h(x) = \dfrac{\int\limits_{x-h}^{x+h} f(y)\ \mu(dy)}{\mu([x-h,x+h])}.
$$
If $\mu$ is a Radon measure, then Lebesgue's differentiation theorem says that $f_h$ converges to $f$ $\mu$-almost-everywhere (see e.g. Herbert Federer's "Geometric Measure Theory", Chapter 2.9).

On the other hand, if $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, then it is known that $f_h \in L_1$ for all $h$, and that $f_h$ converges to $f$ in $L_1$ (i.e. $\Vert f_h - f \Vert_{L_1} \to_{h\to 0} 0$).

My question is: in general, when $\mu$ is any Radon measure, does $f_h$ converge to $f$ in $L_1(\mu)$? In fact, are the $f_h$ even in $L_1(\mu)$? And if not, are there additional assumptions on $\mu$ that make it true?

(If this is indeed true, or at least true modulo assumptions on $\mu$, then I'm also curious of any generalisations to spaces other than $\mathbb R$, similar to how Lebesgue's differentiation theorem generalises to any metric space equipped with a Vitali relation.)

Comment: Sorry, this comment is not helpful, but I liked your line: ’or at least true modulo assumptions on$\mu$’.

Comment: Reference for $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure $\implies L^1$-convergence in the Lebesgue differentiation theorem?

Comment: Sure! "Introduction to Real Analysis" by Christopher Heil, Theorem 5.5.3 (p. 208). It covers the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^d$ for all $d$.

Comment: Do you mind sketching how Federer shows the LDT for Radon measure on $\mathbb R$? Can you prove boundedness of the averaging operator ($f \mapsto f_h : L^1 \to L^1$ in your notation) in that setting?

Comment: For Federer's proof of LDT, I'll see what I can do but at best it'll take time (all told, the proof takes several pages because it is done in a fairly general setting, and I'm unfortunately not too familiar with it). Regarding your other question: I don't really see how to prove that $f \mapsto f_h$ is well-defined (much less bounded) as a function from $L_1$ to $L_1$, and in fact I suspect that with no assumptions on $\mu$ besides Radon, it might not be. Have you got any ideas why it should be?

Comment: @GuillaumeGeoffroy if you ever do find the time, it would be valuable to write up the proof in a more accessible setting (or find another more friendly reference --- Federer is ... https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372196/reference-request-the-theory-of-currents). I wonder if he proceeds via the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function, like the standard proofs of the LDT. If so, I wonder which of the following proofs https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247a.1.06f/notes3.pdf Federer's match most closely, if there is a match at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically a complete answer to your question can be found here https://www.acadsci.fi/mathematica/Vol44/vol44pp0497-0503.pdf BOUNDEDNESS OF AVERAGING OPERATORS ON
GEOMETRICALLY DOUBLING METRIC SPACES
by Jesús M. Aldaz

> **Essentially (part of) Corollary 3.7.** Suppose $(X,d,\mu)$ is s.t. $X$ [is a doubling metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_space) and $\mu$ is a locally finite Borel measure (e.g. any $\mathbb R^n$ and Radon measure $\mu$, right?). Then for every $f ∈ L^p(\mu)$, $1\leq p<\infty$, we have $\|A_r f-f\|_{L^p}\to 0$

(Credit to conversations with fellow grad students for finding this paper: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjuaR.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqdKt.png). See revision history for old version. Aldaz uses the doubling nature of $X$ to control the inner integral in the rightmost expression:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int A_rf(x) d\mu(x) &= \int \int\frac1{\mu(B(x,r))} 1_{[|x-y|<r]}\cdot  |f(y)|d\mu(y) d\mu(x)\\
 &= \int |f(y)| \int \frac{1_{[|x-y|<r]}}{\mu(B(x,r))}  d\mu(y) d\mu(x)
\end{aligned}$$
and hence norm bound the averaging operators $A_r:L^p(\mu) \to L^p(\mu)$; and essentially the argument previously sketched (prove convergence of averages in $L^p$ for $C_c$ functions which is easy, then use density and uniform $L^p\to L^p$ bound on $A_r$) concludes the proof.

Comment: Thanks! Messages up to 12:19 are about the Lebesgue measure, right? Or did I miss something? I'm indeed interested in the possible counter-examples mentioned in the last message! (As well as in any conditions you can add to make the result hold.)

Comment: @GuillaumeGeoffroy yeah messages <12:34 are about Lebesgue measure. But I think the argument works in general (as said in the second to last message) --- if $f_n$ is compactly supported in $B(0,R)$ with extrema $\leq M$ then $A_r f_n$ (for all small enough $r$) is dominated by $M \cdot 1_{B(0,R+1)}$ which is in $L^1$; and a.e. convergence + dominated convergence theorem leads to convergence in $L^1$? Then we should still have $A_r$ has a norm bound of $1$, and density https://planetmath.org/compactlysupportedcontinuousfunctionsaredenseinlp should extend to all of $L^1$ by the 12:18 message.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see where the assumption that all the $f_n$ are below a common constant $M$ comes from. Am I missing something?

Comment: @GuillaumeGeoffroy sorry at that step $n$ is fixed: I fix $f_n$ so that $f_n$ is close to $f$ in $L^1$ (so then $\|A_r(f_n-f)\|_1$ and $\|f_n-f\|_1$ are small), and then the argument in my comment gives $\|A_rf_n - f_n\|_1$ is small.

Comment: Why does $\Vert f_n - f \Vert_1$ small imply $\Vert A(f_n - f) \Vert_1$ small (or even finite)? I don't see how to prove $g \in L_1(\mu)$ implies $A_r g \in L_1(\mu)$ (much less $\Vert A_r g \Vert_1 \leq \Vert g \Vert_1$) when $\mu$ is an arbitrary Radon measure. TBH I am not even sure it is true!

Comment: @GuillaumeGeoffroy yeah this is what the problem boils down to. See the newly edited answer.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I think that answers my question indeed! Now, all I need to do is find out how to make the convergence uniform (I guess through restrictions on $f$), but that's a different question. I'll try to see if I can find the time to answer your question about Federer's proof.